# Write a program that counts fort he user. Let the user enter the starting number, the ending number, and the amount by which to count

Tags: python

[print('help I am new to programming and I need this coded in python')]
#When I am trying to run this program

```
start=int(input("Please enter the starting number:"))
end=int(input("Please enter the ending number:"))
Amt_to_count=int(input("Please enter the amount to count:"))
print('Counting...')
for i in range (start,end,Amt_to_Count):
print(i)
```

It runs the first function, the print, and then nothing else in IDLE.

Comment: Could some show me a working code that does this? Writeaprogramthatcountsfortheuser.Lettheuserenterthe starting number, the ending number, and the amount by which to count.

Comment: print() needs indentation

Answer (score 1):

problem of indentation

```
for i in range (start,end,Amt_to_Count):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, you need indentation to delimit a code block.

```py
for i in range(1, 10):
    print("I am in the for loop")
print("I am not in the for loop")
```

So in your code the `print(i)` is not in the `for` block, you need to indent it.

```py
start=int(input("Please enter the starting number:"))
end=int(input("Please enter the ending number:"))
Amt_to_count=int(input("Please enter the amount to count:"))
print('Counting...')
for i in range (start,end,Amt_to_count):
    print(i)
```